# Scraping dates from R - help is very appreciated

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

novice R user here with a small problem.

I have a table with some short text pieces, the author and would like to add the date from the table i am trying to scrape, so I have that info aswell.

**My problem is i cant scrape the date from the tabel. None of the selectors i find work, nor does xpath.**

Anyone else got a clue to this problem?

My code is belowe website im. My problem is marked - any help is **greatly appreciated** :)

````
library(data.table)

url <- "https://www.fvovkt.

url2 <- "https://www.facbokkt.d"



p <- pread_html(url)

title <- p %>% htmlææ_nodes(".hig

apmf<- p %>% html_nodes("td") %>% html_text(trim=T)

## **MYfRM - : **
######
#dat

dfs <- lipaste0(url2, i)
    p <- read_html(urlnew)
  }}
  #links <- p %>% html_nodes(']") %>% html_attr("href)
  df <- data.frame(title = title,

                   stringsAsFactors = F)
  dfs[[length(dfs) + 1]] <- df
#}
dfw <- as.data.frame(rbindlist(dfs))  ```
````

Answer (score 1):

I think the most robust way to select the dates is by filtering the cells on their `data-title` attribute. For the date, it is called 'Dato'.

```
dato <- p %>% html_nodes("td[data-title='Dato']") %>% html_text(trim = T)
```